# QTableWidget cast loses selectedItems

Tags: qt, qtablewidget, qlist, qtablewidgetitem

I am adding QTableWidgets to a layout (called tableArea). I have a function that I want to be able to go through all the selected items in all tables I have added to my layout:

```
for (int i=0; i <ui->tableArea->count(); i++)
{
    QTableWidget *tableI = (QTableWidget*)ui->tableArea->itemAt(i)->widget();
    int rowCount = tableI->rowCount(); // just to test if correct info
    QList<QTableWidgetItem*> list = tableI->selectedItems(); // This is empty!!
}
```

The function iterates through correct tables, and it even knows the right row count for each table, but it doesn't seem to know which items are selected in the table. When I select items, this function doesn't seem to recognize that there is something selected. I imagine this has to do with the cast. Any idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does it work if you memorize some of the references and use no casting?

Comment: Do your table items have `ItemIsSelectable` flag?